# Azure QnA Maker Managed (preview) - only display Long Answer when receiving a response from bot

Tags: azure, azure-qna-maker

From the Azure QnA Maker documentation:

[The precise answering feature introduced in QnA Maker managed (Preview), allows you to get the precise short answer from the best candidate answer passage present in the knowledge-base for any user query. This feature uses a deep learning model which on runtime, which understands the intent of the user query and detects the precise short answer from the answer passage, if there is a short answer present as a fact in the answer passage.
This feature is on by-default in the test pane, so that you can test the functionality specific to your scenario.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/reference-precise-answering#:%7E:text=In%20the%20QnA%20Maker%20portal%2Cpresent%20in%20the%20answer%20passage.)

In the QnA Maker portal ([qnamaker.ai](http://qnamaker.a)), when you open the test-pane, you will see an option to Display short answer on the top. This option will be selected by-default. When you enter a query in the test pane, you will see a short-answer along with the answer passage, if there is a short answer present in the answer passage (see [this image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/media/conversational-context/test-pane-with-managed.png) for context).

Now, what I want to do is disable the displaying of the short answer from the actual chatbot itself (so that only the long answer is displayed), not just in the test pane in [qnamaker.ai](http://qnamaker.a).

In knowledge base creation in [qnamaker.ai](http://qnamaker.a), I created a QnA pair, with ["Hello" as a question and "Hello 123" as an answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BxIt.png). Saving and training the knowledge base, and publishing it, pushes the knowledgebase changes and the endpoint becomes available for use in my Bot.

Testing this new QnA pair from the Azure Portal via the Test in Web Chat feature in my QnA Web App bot is displaying some weird behaviour: supplying the bot with the phrase "Hello" returns a short answer "123" and a long answer "Hello 123" and this long answer seems to formatted in some weird way.
. Supplying the bot with the phrase "123" returns only the full answer "Hello 123" (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTubc.png)).

Displaying both short and long answers may be disruptive and confusing for the user. This seems to happen for almost all QnA pairs that I've tested. Is there some sort of configuration setting to disable this behaviour?

Comment: 2023: Azure portal >> Bot's App service >> Configuration >> Edit EnablePreciseAnswer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Managed to find a solution to this issue on a question on a [microsoft techcommunity question](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/cognitive-services/qna-maker-bot-returns-both-short-and-long-answer-in-test-in-web/m-p/1882908). This the reply that solves it:

> If you navigate to the bot's app service in Azure portal, go to the
> configuration settings and add the key value pair
> **EnablePreciseAnswer:false** then this will remove the precise answer or
> short answer from the response. You will need to save the change and
> restart the app service for the change to take effect.